# Select all elements with an even id

Tags: xml, xpath

Id is attribute of book and book is element in bookstore element.
This is what I am trying to do:

```
 /bookstore/book[id mod 2=0]
```

It's not working.

I think I have syntax problem but I couldn't find solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` is an attribute, so `@id`:

```
 /bookstore/book[@id mod 2=0]
```

will select

```
<book id="2"/>
<book id="4"/>
```

given this XML:

```
<bookstore>
  <book id="1"/>
  <book id="2"/>
  <book id="3"/>
  <book id="4"/>
  <book id="5"/>
</bookstore>
```